# plural possessive form of a mutated plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, possessive-s-vs-of

Here are two examples of mutated plurals:
more than one goose= geese; 
more than one man= men

1)Say you had 2 or more groups of geese. I.e. group #1= African geese & group #2=buff geese. If you wanted to associate these groups together but still observe the fact that they are different types of geese, would you say geeses? (Buff geese + African geese = geeses)
Taking this one step further, if these two distinct groups of geese share in the possession of something, would geeses' be correct? Say, one type of illness is common to two sorts of geese. [illness common to Buff geese(=Buff geese's illness) + the same illness is common to African geese(=African geese's illness)    --> geeses' illness? ]

2)Say you had 2 or more groups of men: men from France(Frenchmen), men from England (Englishmen), and men from Ireland (Irishmen). Let's say you want to refer to the "European charm" that these groups of men have in common while still noting that there ARE different and distinct groups of men involved(i.e. different people groups--> peoples). Would you say the mens' charm?

I guess I'm just curious if you can make the sum of multiple groups possessive while keeping a distinction between these groups intact. 
(distinct GROUPS with similar possession)

Comment: Is _mutated plural_ a thing? I'm not a linguist, but the term I've heard is _irregular plural_ (similarly for verbs with irregular conjugations).

Comment: We already talk of the "fishes of the sea" or the "peoples of the earth", so the "geeses of the world" is not too far fetched,

Comment: @ Barmar  "In linguistics, a change in a vowel sound caused by a sound in the following syllable." See http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/Mutation.htm

Comment: @Martin How about a list of all the ones we don't talk about for balance? *the mens of North America / *the childrens of the African nations / *the mices we have studied / *the cactis nearing extinction / the teeths of various mammals / / / ?

Comment: The fact that there are some examples, even exceptional examples, does not of course mean that those examples set rules.

Comment: Why would the form of the plural make any difference here? If they were Buff dogs and African dogs, would you say _dogses’_ diseases? (Or if there are l different kinds of diseases associated with each group of dog, _dogses’ diseaseses_?!?)

Comment: @Christina OK, so mutation is a thing in pronunciation, but that doesn't seem to be related to irregular forms of words.

Comment: @Martin I guess I could've asked about irregular plurals as a whole, but the specific examples that I was curious about did happen to be mutated.

Comment: @Janus I believe the difference is that there are several specific words that exist to identify groups (i.e for dogs:kennel, pack, cry, etc.) for many regular plurals. Since these words exist, we use them instead(i.e. packs' diseases). As for the second question--regarding different kinds of diseases associated with each group of dog--I'm not sure that you could still group them together in possession. My whole point in asking was to clarify upon the idea of distinct groups with similar possession.

Comment: There is only one rule, and it applies universally, whether it’s the pope’s problem, the men’s or geese’s problem, the foxes’ problem, or the corpora’s problem. There is no mystery here.

Comment: @tchrist But what about the plural possessive of people? It is peoples'

Comment: @Christina Yes, because _people_ is **singular**. One people, two peoples (in technical usages). But the genitive of _people_ meaning ‘people in general’ is _people’s_ and doesn't have a plural form at all. All the forms Martin listed above, as well as several others, are plural forms of singular nouns that just happen to be used collectively (often with notional agreement and a plural verb) in the singular. Notional agreement doesn't imply grammatical plurality. _Fishes_ is just an alternative plural because the more common plural is identical to the singular, like _sheeps_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I’ve noticed that people are fond of saying that *people* is one of those pluralia tantum they always warn you about, but I’m a person who thinks it just has a singular that’s been the victim of suppletion. :)

Comment: @Janus Then I guess my question would be, where do you draw the line on "singular" words that refer to groups? Is "people" the only exception? person (person's) --plural--> people (people's) --plural--> peoples (peoples')    vs.    man (man's) --plural--> men (men's) --plural--> mens? (mens' ?)

Comment: @Christina There's a difference between _grammatical number_ (whether something is a singular or a plural noun) and _semantic number_ (whether something refers to a singular or plural physical entity). _People_ is always grammatically singular (its grammatical plural being _peoples_), but it can be used as a semantic plural, referring to a number of persons. Verb agreement in English can be either grammatical or notional/semantic, depending on context, which is why _this (Bantu) people is_, but _these people are_. There are other words that function like this.

Comment: With nouns traditionally almost always non-count and thus taking singular agreement, groups/types of can be countified: The two major coffees are arabica and canephora. / Different wheats will show different tolerances to the disease. With nouns already count, it's best to stick to 'types / species / gaggles etc' of geese etc.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of 'correct' usage, it's wrong to do what the OP is suggesting. Neither written English nor its spoken form has an accepted mechanism for making "the sum of multiple groups possessive while keeping a distinction between these groups intact" by inflection. Joint possession by multiple groups of the same type can be expressed, of course - but it is done analytically rather than by inflection.

1) You can say, 'an illness of both buff and African geese', or, 'a buff and African geese's illness', or a couple of other similar phrasings. The best choice of phrasing will depends on context.

Writing "Geeses" or "geeses's" in ANY context would mark the author as either a learner, or hopelessly illiterate.

2) You'd have to say something like 'the charm of all these men', or 'those men's charm' ... while doing what you can to remove ambiguity.

However, in very informal and colloquial oral conversations only, some native speakers DO use these kinds of 'recursive' plurals and possessives,  ... but always with the awareness that it's 'bad English'. For example, someone might say, "Chimps and humans are two different specieses.Both specieses's behaviours are complex." ... but only for humorous effect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you *can* "make the sum of multiple groups possessive while keeping a distinction between these groups intact" - you just have to use a few more words to ensure the distinction. Your question already contains the answer: the "illness is common to two sorts of geese". If you're really keen to use the possessive, you could say "the Buff and African geese's illnesses" or "the Buff geese's and African geese's illnesses." Similarly, you could say "the French and English men's charm" or for greater clarity, "Frenchmen and Englishmen share a common European charm".

In all cases, the only time it would be grammatically correct to add an "s" to an already plural word would be if you're treating the word as a single item for counting purposes, e.g. "there are three geeses in that sentence." Even so, this would be an awkward usage and would be better rephrased to avoid the plural plural, viz. "the word 'geese' is used three times."

Answer (score -3):

Since "geese" is plural, the possessive form would be "geese's." In the second part of your question, you used geese in an entirely different context that made the word singular instead of plural. In that context, the plural of geese is geeses. If you have a plural possessive of geese, you do indeed get geeses'.

Comment: No, it does not matter whether *geese* is singular or plural: its possessive still adds apostrophe-s.  Compare *geese’s* with *fleece’s*, *niece’s*, and *nieces’*.

Comment: “In the second part of your question, you used geese in an entirely different context that made the word singular instead of plural” — That was the intention, yes, but English doesn’t work like that. You simply cannot just take a plural form and decide it’s now going to work as a singular form. _One houses, two houseses_ makes no sense, and nor does _one geese, two geeses_.